# Mathematica cannot find CUDA driver

Tags: linux, cudalink

I have successfully installed CUDA 5.0 on my Ubuntu 12.10, with driver 304.54, toolkit and samples. Running deviceQuery gives me a successful output:

```
    Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

      Device 0: "GeForce 9500 GT"
      CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          5.0 / 5.0
      CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    1.1
      Total amount of global memory:                 512 MBytes (536543232 bytes)
      ( 4) Multiprocessors x (  8) CUDA Cores/MP:    32 CUDA Cores

      etc...
```

bandwidthTest is also successful:

```
     Device 0: GeForce 9500 GT
     Quick Mode

     Host to Device Bandwidth, 1 Device(s)
     PINNED Memory Transfers
       Transfer Size (Bytes)    Bandwidth(MB/s)
       33554432         5628.6

     etc...
```

I stress that my card is listed among the compatible CUDA cards for Mathematica. However, in Mathematica 9.0.1.0, running

```
    Needs["CUDALink`"]
    CUDAQ[]
```

returns

```
    False
```

running

```
    CUDAInformation[]
```

returns

```
    CUDAInformation::invdriv : CUDA was not able to find a valid CUDA driver.
    Refer to CUDALink System Requirements
```

and running

```
    CUDADriverVersion[]
```

returns

```
    CUDADriverVersion::nodriv : 
    CUDALink was not able to locate the NVIDIA driver binary.
    Refer to CUDALink System Requirements
```

So it cannot find both the binary and the libraries, and referring to the CUDALink system requirements help page is not helping. Any ideas?

Comment: Ziofil.. How do you set up the path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ahh!
The solution is to export `NVIDIA_DRIVER_LIBRARY_PATH` to the *full* path `/usr/lib/libnvidia-tls.so.304.54` and `CUDA_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/usr/lib/libcuda.so.304.54`! (for my driver version)

What a lovely way to waste an afternoon.

Answer (score 7):

Please check where your `libnvidia-tls.so.*` and your `libcuda.so` is installed. When I'm not mistaken, they are under `/usr/lib` in ubuntu. Now read [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CUDALink/tutorial/Setup.html) and find that *Mathematica* expects these libraries to be in `/usr/lib64` for a 64bit Linux.

Therefore, close Mathematica and open a terminal and execute (you have to change the library version according to your system)

```bash
export NVIDIA_DRIVER_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/libnvidia-tls.so.310.32
export CUDA_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/libcuda.so
mathematica
```

In the starting *Mathematica* try to run `CUDAQ` again and if this succeeds, then you know where the problem is.

From there you have the opportunity to either make links of the libraries to `/usr/lib64` or you set the above environment variables in your *Mathematica* application launcher.

If you want to create a custom application launcher for your *Mathematica* which uses changed environment variables, you can do it by using `env` in the command line. For instance my launcher (because I need some Intel libs) looks like that

[image]

where the content of the *Command* is something like this

```shell
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.117/tbb/lib/intel64   
 /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/Executables/Mathematica
```

Comment: You are right, they are in `/usr/lib`. Though, exporting those environment variables by hand does not seem to do anything (other than changing the values of `GPUTools\`Internal\`$CUDALibraryPath` and 
`GPUTools\`Internal\`$NVIDIADriverLibraryPath` to the exported values). I even tried to create simlinks to `/usr/lib64`, but no luck. Darn.

Comment: @Ziofil Sorry, it was pretty late here and I had my Ubuntu already off and was writing it from memory without trying it. Of course you need to specify the location of the library itself. I fixed my post.